# CE6 USB Unidentified when connected at boot but ok if connected after boot

Tags: usb, windows-ce, ftdi

I have an FTDI USB cable connecting a device to CE6.0 R3.

If I wait for the CE6 device to boot then plug in the USB no problem.

If I have the USB connected at boot time it says it is unidentified and asks for a driver name.

Am using FTDI VCP.

Appreciate any help to get this working.

I dont have platform builder, I am using the manufacturers standard image and the CE device basically boots of a clean image every time (windows etc directories are volatile)

TIA

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the OEM's USB Host driver (or the underlying platform interrupt handler).  They're not properly handling the connection interrupts.  Only they, or someone with the BSP and source for at least that driver and maybe the system interrup handler, are going to be able to fix this.